# Nginx custom error_page not using the specified page?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, php

I'm trying to get a custom 404 page to show up on a specific server. The 404 error page is located at /www/example/html/404.php and the website root is /www/example/html/

Currently, any non-existant page yields this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ojd5.png, and does not seem to be loading my custom 404 page (which has some custom styles and menus). I've been struggling with this for a few days now with different .conf settings, my current nginx.conf is below. I am on Ubuntu 12, Nginx 1.1.19 and using php-fpm.

```
user       www-data;
worker_processes  5;
error_log  logs/error.log;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include    mime.types;
    include    fastcgi_params;
    index    index.php index.html index.htm;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log   logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile     on;
    tcp_nopush   on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    server {
            listen 80;

            server_name example.com;
            client_max_body_size 20M;
            root /www/example/html;

            access_log logs/example.access.log;

            location / {
                    index index.php index.html index.htm;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
            }

            location @rewrite {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
            }

            location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
                    access_log off;
                    expires max;
            }

            location /404.php {
                    internal;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    error_page 404 /404.php;
                    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny  all;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do the following:

```
error_page 404 /www/example/html/404.php;

location /404.php {
  return 404;
}
```

What do your access and error logs show?

Second option. Define a custom 404 page for everything your "server" context:

```
server {
...

error_page 404 /www/example/html/404.php;

...
}
```

Comment: Most recent access log http://pastebin.com/CqjHWKvb - still didn't load the correct error page. I put the "error_page" code in the "PHP" block, should it be in the "/" block instead?

Comment: If all you need to do is to show an specific custom page on 404, do the following:


server {
...
error_page   404 =  /www/example/html/404.php;

...
}

Whie trouble shooting please comment every single "location" block. Then try to access a non existent resource. You should see the custom error page. 

BTW, ensure the nginx daemon have the appropriate permissions on the "404.php" file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the `location ~ \.php$` block to use:

```
error_page 404 = /404.php;
```

Or

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    error_page 404 @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/html/404.php
}
```

Comment: proxy_pass failed with error "proxy_pass" may not have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside the "if" statement, or inside the "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:181"